# How to add a dictionary of varying hierarchy in a listbox or in a treeview for python 2.5

Tags: python, json, dictionary, treeview, python-2.5

I have a dictionary of multiple hierarchy. This dictionary is not constant and keeps changing. I am using python 2.5 (not planning on changing the version due to compatibility with other software). So, my question

1. How do I implement the dictionary in a tree hierarchy.
2. Is there anyway I can implement a tree in python 2.5. (There is a treeview in python 2.7 in ttk which is absent in python 2.5)
3. Also on a separate note, it would be very helpful if somebody can help me in getting json work in python 2.5

My dictionary goes like this `{a, {b, {c, d}, e, f}, g}`  (this dictionary is not constant and keeps changing)

And I want the tree to be displayed as

```
a
   b
      c
      d
   e
   f
g
```

Any support regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Try simplejson instead of json for python version 2.5 :p